# Swift type erasure - for this case?

Tags: swift, generics, type-erasure

I have requirement of implementing TypeConverter and later use it as variable type. Inspired by ObjectMapper I have defined following protocol:

```
protocol TypeConverter {
    associatedtype A
    associatedtype B

    func transformFrom(fromType: A?) -> B?

    func transformTo(toType: B?) -> A?
}
```

Concrete implementation is:

```
class IntToStringTypeConverter: TypeConverter {

    typealias A = Int
    typealias B = String

    func transformFrom(fromType: Int?) -> String? {
        guard let fromType = fromType else { return nil }
        return String(fromType)
    }

    func transformTo(toType: String?) -> Int? {
        guard let toType = toType else { return nil }
        return Int(toType)
    }
}
```

Because protocol TypeConverter has associatedtype, I cannot declare it as variable, for example: var converter: TypeConverter, but I need such feature. The solution to such case is using typeErasure. By following this link https://medium.com/@NilStack/swift-world-type-erasure-5b720bc0318a it should be possible, but I don't have real idea how.

Here is my try, but its not right :)... Is this even solve-able this way? Or I should use this one: https://appventure.me/2017/12/10/patterns-for-working-with-associated-types ?

```
class AnyTypeConverter<Y, Z>: TypeConverter {

    typealias A = Y
    typealias B = Z

    private let _transformFrom: (Z?) -> Y?
    private let _transformTo: (Y?) -> Z?

    init<W: TypeConverter>(_ iFormTypeConverter: W) where W.A == Y, W.B == Z {
        self._transformFrom = iFormTypeConverter.transformFrom
        self._transformTo = iFormTypeConverter.transformTo
    }

    func transformFrom(modelType: Y?) -> Z? {
        return transformFrom(modelType: modelType)
    }

    func transformTo(iFormType: Z?) -> Y? {
        return transformTo(iFormType: iFormType)
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the use case? FWIW I much prefer using separate `StringConvertable` and `IntConvertable` protocols and the desired Types adhering with extensions.

Comment: Also why do you need a `TypeConverter` object. you should be able to declare `var converter: IntToStringConverter`

Comment: @gadu thanks for replying. See the comment below please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After implementing two cells I have found out that I can simplify this thing a bit, and go with only one associated type :). The type used in the cell is actually defined by the UI component - if there is UITextField, then type will be String, if I implement custom stepper, it will be Int (for example). If I want to make my cell generic, then it should work with Any type, for which I can write converter between model and (pre)defined cellType.

```
protocol FormTypeConverter {

    associatedtype FormType

    func fromModelToForm(_ value: Any?) -> FormType?

    func fromFormToModel(_ value: FormType?) -> Any?
}
```

With that I can use simple type erasure as follows (source in links in the first post)

```
struct AnyFormTypeConverter<T>: FormTypeConverter {

    // MARK: - Variables

    private let fromModelToFormWrapper: (Any?) -> T?
    private let fromFormToModelWrapper: (T?) -> Any?

    init<Y: FormTypeConverter>(_ formTypeConverter: Y) where Y.FormType == T {
        self.fromModelToFormWrapper = formTypeConverter.fromModelToForm
        self.fromFormToModelWrapper = formTypeConverter.fromFormToModel
    }

    func fromModelToForm(_ value: Any?) -> T? {
        return fromModelToFormWrapper(value)
    }

    func fromFormToModel(_ value: T?) -> Any? {
        return fromFormToModel(value)
    }
}
```

This case implementation suits excellent. Already implemented two completely different forms in no-time :)

Answer (score 4):

This is not really a good use for a protocol with associated types. PATs are very complicated tools, and there's really no reason for it in this case at all. You don't even need a type-eraser so much as just a struct:

```
struct TypeConverter<Model, Form> {
    let transformFrom: (Model) -> Form?
    let transformTo: (Form) -> Model?
}

let stringToInt = TypeConverter(transformFrom:String.init,
                                transformTo:Int.init)

stringToInt.transformFrom(123)
stringToInt.transformTo("x")
```

You of course could make this conform to `TypeConverter` if you wanted to (and I can update to add that), but I recommend dropping the protocol entirely and just using structs. This is very close to how `Formatter` works.

Comment: I am aware how formatters work - you won't believe but I have started very similar way as you did, but somehow it didn't meet my requirements.

Comment: I am aware how formatters work - you won't believe but I have started very similar way as you did, but somehow it didn't meet my requirements. I am working on FormRowDescription object, which may have converter to map data type between DataModel and CellType - so it maybe String/Int, Float/Int - anything :). So I need to make that generic. The object FormRowDescription should be for all cases of course. That's why I it is so important to me, to have option to declare it as var converter: ConverterType... it that type erasure won't go, it it still an option to declare converter as Any, Any....

Comment: protocol AnyConverter { // VERY UGLY SOLUTION
    
    func fromModel(value: Any?) -> Any?
    func toModel(value: Any?) -> Any?
}

class IntoStringAnyConverter: AnyConverter {
    
    func fromModel(value: Any?) -> Any? {
        guard let value = value as? Int else { return nil }
        return String(value)
    }
    
    func toModel(value: Any?) -> Any? {
        guard let value = value as? String else { return nil }
        return Int(value)
    }
}

Comment: class Test {
    var anyConverter: AnyConverter
    
    init(anyConverter: AnyConverter) {
        self.anyConverter = anyConverter
    }
}

let converter = IntoStringAnyConverter()
let test = Test(anyConverter: converter)

Comment: The example above suits my needs but it is DAMN ugly. That's why I have tried to solve it more fancy way.. if it is possible of course

Comment: Other solutions I've seen that look like this have generally worked out to be very over-designed, and stepping back to handling the actual cases that were in the program in question turned out to be quite simple with very little generics. So first, make sure this flexibility is something that is critical to you, and not just working around writing a couple of classes (if it is, just write the couple of classes and move on). Lay out how the caller is going to actually use this, and let's see what problem you're really solving. I think you're fighting the type system.

Comment: It seems very strange that the thing that owns the `FormRowDescription` doesn't know ahead of time what type it needs. That suggests the generic is at the wrong level.

Comment: The fact that you're mapping to "CellType" and consider that to possibly be "Int" is also very suspicious. Cells IMO should accept a full Model object and should lay themselves out. Sometimes it's worth an extra view model layer, but only if the formatting is either very complicated or reused a lot in this program. If you want more of my opinions on how to tie together models and cells, see https://youtu.be/c3Kg3c8vqsc

Comment: I would be much easier for you if you would have the whole picture. Yes I am mapping between "model" and "cellType", because the cells must be reusable betweens forms - and if the UI component uses stepper (for example), the cell may have Int as a Type. If there will be UITextField, String will be the "cellType". The cells will not accept the "whole" model due reusability and because I don't want to tie cells to 1 model - they have to work for any "model".

Comment: The FormRowDescription is an object, which holds configuration for the cell - for example what kind of Keyboard it should have, or is it enabled (read only mode) and so on. It can contain value, in case this is some form of some description cell, where description is not part of the model, but of FormDescription. When cell receives value from model, then this is seperate parameter. Also thanks for the link, will take a look if I can simplify anything.